# USB device not found in lxsession mode

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+, linux

When I use the desktop mode of Raspbian, I can find the connected USB device on my Pi in this path:

```
/media/pi/'My Usb Disk'
```

But when I use chromium web kiosk mode and lxsession I cannot find the connected USB device in the **/media/pi** path. How can get the path of USB device in Raspbian OS in all situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the instructions:

**1.** Figure out what is the name of USB drive on `/dev`:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

It should be like sda1, sdb2, etc. Plug and unplug to making sure about that.

**2.** Create a mount point whichever you prefer:

```
sudo mkdir /home/pi/drive
```

**3.** Give the permission for the mount point:

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/drive
```

Note that if you have logged in by root user, step 3 is ineffective.

**4.** Mount the USB drive:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/pi/drive -o uid=pi,gid=pi
```

Bear it in mind that if you have logged in by root user, remove `-o uid=pi,gid=pi` of step 4. instead of `sda1`, put the name of step 1. [*Source*](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-mount-a-usb-flash-disk-on-the-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: Thank you, dear Mohammad. my problem solved. :)

Comment: @ParsaKarami Well, My pleasure. By this answer?

Comment: yeah, thanks, I want to read file from a USB device and cannot do that before the mount operation.